# Django-Q set Q_CLUSTER 'sync': True doesn't work for unit tests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-q

I am using Django-Q to send async emails with Django 2.2, DRF 3.9 and Postgres 10.9

The setup works fine except when it comes to unit tests.
I refer to the following issue which is the exact same thing I am facing:
https://github.com/Koed00/django-q/issues/266

As per the link, one of  the solutions was to do change the sync setting to 'True' for testing purposes.

This is what i have in tests.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.Q_CLUSTER['sync'] = True


class UserAPITestCase(APITransactionTestCase):
    print(settings.Q_CLUSTER)
```

'print' shows that the 'sync':True has been added, but the async_task still runs in async mode.

However if I were to add the sync setting in the settings file directly everything works as it should and the async_task runs synchronously.

It's like django-q isn't taking in the setting if it is updated later. How do I fix that?

Comment: How do you fix that. Currently i have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

```
from django_q.conf import Conf

class UserAPITestCase(APITransactionTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Conf.SYNC = True
    def test_do_something_with_async_task(self):
        pass
    def tearDown(self):
        Conf.SYNC = False
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing

```
from django.test import override_settings
from django.conf import settings


@override_settings(Q_CLUSTER={**settings.Q_CLUSTER, 'sync': True})
class UserAPITestCase(APITransactionTestCase):
    pass
```

Comment: I get the same results with this unfortunately. Sync doesn't get updated to True

Comment: Seems that there might be an issue with override_settings and DRF

Comment: If this solution does not work, I would suggest you to follow best practice for handling settings in different environments, like staging, testing, development and production. It is to create a base settings file and inherit files for other environments from it. Here is a [helpful article](https://medium.com/@ayarshabeer/django-best-practice-settings-file-for-multiple-environments-6d71c6966ee2) about it.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same idea. For now I'm doing this as a workaround.